# Why would images and script file paths not resolve after deployment in an Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, deployment, iis-7, relative-path

I have developed an Asp.Net MVC application in Visual Studio 2010. So far so good. In terms of path resolution for images and script execution, everything runs perfect within Visual Studio. As I am using the default template of MVC I am using "../../Script/*****.js" kind of path. After I build the package for deployment and deploy in IIS, the images and the script references stop working. I think it might be a path resolution issue. I tried with "~/Script/.js" but it does not work either. Could somebody suggest why this is happening?

Comment: you should use `@Url.Content("your relative path")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using two things in any of your asp.net MVC projects.

1) Using a Layout for common site elements using  _Layout.cshtml and include all your javascript and css files inside that and do not put it on the any other .cshtml pages unless necessary required. [see here how to use  _Layout.cshtml](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

2) Second thing always use @Url.Content() directive to define your paths e.g

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This two way always helps you and never have problem even if you deploy package.

Hope above helps.

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem we get in  asp.net when we use URL Rewriting and asp.net mvc have a URL Rewriting by default.

so when you use script or urls and js then you set your path like this .

```
@Url.Content("~/Your Url or Your script or Your js File ") ;
```

i think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

MVC has built in functions that generates url's, so use those instead of hard code url

```
@Url.Content("~/yourpath")
```

When you deploy your webapp onto IIS, your site is set to run as Virtual Directory so the website root is no longer the same as the application root, MVC has 
`ActionLinks,Url.Contents` to resolve Url's.

[MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx)